# How to use Applicative operators for the Maybe and List Monads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

`Maybe` and `List` are monads and I can use the bind operator `>>=` as expected, as in:

```
Prelude> (Just 0) >>= (\x -> Just(succ x))
Just 1
```

However if try to use the `<$>` applicative operator, I get an error:

```
Prelude> (Just succ) <$> (Just 0)

<interactive>:16:6: Not in scope: ‘<$>’
```

How to correct my input so that this last expression evaluates to `Just 1`.

Comment: import [**`Control.Applicative`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You error arises because you didn't `<$>` is not is scope (just as compiler said). The `<$>` operator is provided by module `Data.Functor` and `Control.Applicative`. So just load the module into ghci:

```
:m Control.Applicative
```

or if you are not in ghci

```
import Control.Applicative
```

note that starting with `base-4.8` (ghc 7.10), `<$>` is included in Prelude and thus imported by default.

However that's not your only problem. `<$>` (`fmap`) allow you to apply the function to some value inside the Functor/Monad/Applicative. For example

```
succ <$> Just 0
-- => Just 1
succ <$> Nothing
-- => Nothing
fmap succ (Just 0)
-- => Just 1
```

But if you want to apply a function which is itself inside the Functor/Monad/Applicative you need `<*>`

```
Just succ <*> Just 1
-- => Just 2
Nothing <*> Just 1
-- => Nothing
Just succ <*> Nothing
-- => Nothing
```

This operator is extremely useful for functions with several arguments:

```
(+) <$> Just 1 <*> Just 2
-- Just (+1) <*> Just 2        (intermediate step)
-- => Just 3
```

Comment: You might want to use `:m +Control.Applicative`. Without the + it "unimports" all other imported modules. You can also use a - to unimport a single, specific module.

Answer (score 9):

`<$>` and `<*>` are defined in `Control.Applicative`, so you need to import them:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
```

`<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`, so, for your example, you need to use `<*>` which lifts function application over an applicative:

```
(Just succ) <*> (Just 0)
```